# mysql_query return values

Tags: php, sql

The `mysql_query` function in php returns `TRUE` on success and `FALSE` on failure.

My question is what is considered success ?

In other words, what is returned when there is nothing from a `SELECT` statement, or if there is an `UPDATE` and nothing that matches the `WHERE` clause.  Does it return FALSE or something like an empty resource ?

I'm trying to differentiate between a db error, and an empty result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Success means "no errors". Getting zero rows is not an error.

**Edit:** Just checked the [manual page](http://es2.php.net/mysql_query) and the explanation is pretty clear (not sure where you got yours):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or **FALSE on
>   error**.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or **FALSE on error**.

Comment: I read that too, but I thought success could possibly not include an empty result set.

Answer (score 3):

`TRUE` means no errors.

If you want to know the number of rows in the `resultset` use: `mysql_num_rows($result)`.

If it is an update and you want to know if rows have changed use: `mysql_affected_rows($result)`.

Comment: WFM. Is there as simple an equivalent in PDO?